# In JavaScript, what is the simplest way to insert text into a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, parsing

I have an issue where I need to take a string (which is a [query string](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/query_string#Noun)) in JavaScript and transform it into another query string (to avoid clashes).

The original string I have comes in as:

```
fieldA=10&fieldB=10&fieldC=10&fieldD=10&arrayfieldA=100&arrayfieldA=200
```

And I want to take a prefix (in my case it will be something like "slides[0]." and put it in front of all of the items, so I end up with:

```
slides[0].fieldA=10&slides[0].fieldB=10&slides[0].fieldC=10&slides[0].fieldD=10&slides[0].arrayfieldA=100&slides[0].arrayfieldA=200
```

In JavaScript, what is the simplest way to transform the first string into the second?

I could use

- Simple find / "replace()"  (.replace("&", "&slides[0]")
- Convert to array and then spit back to a concatenated string
- others?

Currently I am doing this:

```
function EnrichString(startString, prefix) {
    return prefix + startString.replace("&", "&" + prefix);
}
```

But I wanted to confirm if there are any gotchas with this approach?

Comment: you're asking simplest but the title says "efficient". These are very different and even "simplest" can have multiple definitions. Please be more clear

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have the solutions you tried proved to be too inefficient?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer or maybe the OP asks for just _any_ way :)

Comment: @ Matt Burland - updated questions with the options that i have used.  They all work but i am trying to figure out if there are any gotchas

Comment: If your solutions work, then this sounds like [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In first place, how this original query string is generated? You should investigate there instead, i guess...

Comment: Update the question to hopefully get it "off hold"

Comment: The *gotcha* with your current `EnrichString()` approach is that it will only replace the first occurrence of `&` with `"&" + prefix` which excludes any following `&`s and the initial `?fieldA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var queryStringParts = queryString.split('&');
var pairs = queryStringParts.map(function(str) { return str.split('=') })
var rewrittenParts = pairs.map(function(pair){
                          return 'slides[0].' + pair[0] + '=' + pair[1]
                     });
var newQuerystring = rewrittenParts.join('&');
```

As was pointed out in the comments, in this specific case we could skip the split into pairs step and just do

```
var queryStringParts = queryString.split('&');
var rewrittenParts = queryStringParts.map(function(part) {
                          return 'slides[0].' + part
                     });
var newQuerystring = rewrittenParts.join('&');
```

Comment: Why split by `=` if you're doing nothing but joining them back together by `=`?

Comment: @Travesty3 I do join back with an =, just manually using string concatenation in the third step.

Comment: I know, I'm wondering why do you split each part by `=` at all? You're just joining back together, not modifying that part of the string at all.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean, I could just prefix. Good point, force of habit.

Comment: why not just `newQuerystring = "slides[0]." + queryStringParts.join("&slides[0].")` i think it would be faster,but at least its simpler and it could be a one liner too:

`newQuerystring = "slides[0]." + queryString.split('&').join("&slides[0].") `

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco Been a long time but that could work I think. My solution is more generic template for solving this kind of issue but you make a good point. I wouldn't worry about speed though - how many querystring parameters can there possibly be?